# setlocale raising errno while a non-NULL value is returned

Tags: c, posix, locale, errno, setlocale

Consider the following minimalistic code fragment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    const char *locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    if (errno == ENOENT) {
        printf("Locale %s unavailable.\n", locale ? locale : "<unknown>");
    } else if (errno) {
        printf("setlocale() failed: errno = %d\n", errno);
        perror("setlocale() failed");
    }

    if (locale) {
        printf("Current locale: %s\n", locale);
    }

    return errno;
}
```

This runs successfully on a number of UNIX boxes (Solaris 8, Debian Linux 8, OpenBSD 5.8). There's a few exceptions, however.

According to the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html), `setlocale` returns `NULL` if locale specified by the process environment (`LC_ALL` et al.) is unavailable (i. e. the corresponding files are missing and need to be generated with `localegen` or a similar tool). Testing reveals that [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) is set to `ENOENT` in this case, but on one of *Debian 7* boxes `setlocale` returns a valid non-`NULL` locale string **and** sets `errno` to `ENOENT`.

The other strange behaviour is exhibited by *Cygwin*: for each of the single-byte Cyrillic locales (`ru_RU.CP1251`, `ru_RU.CP866`, `ru_RU.KOI8-R`, `ru_RU.ISO-8859-5`), `setlocale` returns a correct locale string **and** sets `errno` to `EILSEQ`. At the same time, `ru_RU.UTF-8` is not affected.

How can any of the above cases be further diagnosed?

Comment: Make sure to set `errno` to zero *before* calling `setlocale` because `setlocale` (just like all POSIX functions) will leave `errno` unchanged if it is successful.

Comment: @FUZxxl: thanks, forgot that, but setting `errno` to 0 before `setlocale` invocation doesn't change the whole picture: I still get `ENOENT` and `EILSEQ` for valid and available locales.

Comment: @FUZxxl That is not true at all. POSIX explicitly says: "The setting of errno after a successful call to a function is unspecified unless the description of that function specifies that errno shall not be modified." `setlocale` doesn't say that it won't change errno, so it is allowed to do so.

Comment: @Art Okay, seems like I was misinformed in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX [does not specify](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setlocale.html) how `setlocale` affects `errno` (see section ERRORS where it says “no errors are specified”). You can safely disregard the value of `errno` after a `setlocale` call.

An implementation of `setlocale` should never touch `errno`, but it seems like some of the implementations you tested are buggy in this regard. I recommend you to file a bug report against the projects that supplied the faulty `setlocale` implementation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure *Cygwin*'s `setlocale` implementation raises `EILSEQ` because of the underlying call to `iconv`.

Comment: To be more precise:  *The value of errno shall be defined only after a call to a function for which it is explicitly stated to be set and until it is changed by the next function call or if the application assigns it a value. The value of errno should only be examined when it is indicated to be valid by a function's return value.*  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html#tag_16_110  Since most functions specify something like  *the functions shall return -1 and set errno to indicate the error* (from `read`), `errno` will be indeterminate unless the call failed.

Comment: So in this case, since the `setlocale()` call does not explicitly set `errno` when it succeeds, the value of `errno` is undefined.  Even setting it to zero before calling `setlocale()` wouldn't guarantee its value after the call.

Answer (score 1):

In general when it comes to most functions from POSIX you are not supposed to look at `errno` unless the function returned an error.

POSIX documents it [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html).

> The value of errno should only be examined when it is indicated to be valid by a function's return value.

Functions are allowed to change `errno` even when they succeed:

> The setting of errno after a successful call to a function is unspecified unless the description of that function specifies that errno shall not be modified.

This happens quite commonly where a function tries one thing, that fails, tries another thing and that succeeds. It's often too expensive or too hard to preserve errno around system calls in libraries.

Looking at `errno` without the function signaling an error to you is a bug, you can't do that.